# Timezone incorrect for old date

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I'm using the code below to determine if a particular datetime is GMT or GMT+1 depending on daylight saving time (British Summer Time).

```
Private Function getFormattedDate(ByVal inDate As DateTime) As Object
    Dim sDate As String = inDate.ToString("s")

    sDate = sDate.Replace("T", " ")

    Dim zone As TimeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone
    Dim offset As TimeSpan = zone.GetUtcOffset(inDate)

    sDate &= " GMT+" & offset.TotalHours.ToString.PadLeft(2, "0"c) & ":00"

    Return sDate

End Function
```

This appears to work well and returns the results, for example :

29-Jan-2018 = "2018-01-29 09:23:54 GMT+00:00"

26-Mar-2018 = "2018-03-26 09:23:54 GMT+01:00" - After Last Sunday in March

However, if I use the date 26-Oct-1993 it returns the following :

26-Oct-1993 = "1993-10-26 09:23:54 GMT+01:00"

Which is incorrect - as we know Between 1972 and 1995, BST ended at 02:00 GMT on the fourth Sunday in October - which is the 24th.  Can anyone see an issue with the code I am using here or with my understanding of British Summer time?

Comment: What OS are you running on? I seem to recall that on some only the current DST rules are used as if they've been applicable throughout history.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 64-bit, we've found the problem when passing the date to Linux which is calculating it correctly